# Using jQuery's deferreds

Tags: jquery-deferred

I have been reading about jQuery's deferreds, but I can't quite grasp how to use them.

I have the following deeply nested code

```
Repository.Projects.GetStages(function (data) {
    var stagesXml = $.parseXML(data.d);

    Repository.Projects.GetBenefits(function (data) {
        var benefitsXml = $.parseXML(data.d);

        Repository.Projects.GetPriorities(function (data) {
            var prioritiesXml = $.parseXML(data.d);

            Repository.Projects.GetDifficulties(function (data) {
                var difficultiesXml = $.parseXML(data.d);

                Repository.Projects.GetFactors(function (data) {
                    var factorsXml = $.parseXML(data.d);

                    Repository.Projects.GetRatings(function (data) {
                        var ratingsXml = $.parseXML(data.d);

                        Repository.Projects.GetProjectRatings(selectedPersonIdEncrypted, passDate, function (data) {
                            var dataDoc = UTL.Utility.prototype.setDomDocument(data.d);
                            var xsltDoc = UTL.Utility.prototype.setXslt("Xslt/UserRating/ProjectRatings.xslt");
                            var html = UTL.Utility.prototype.transform(dataDoc, xsltDoc, [
                                ['stages', stagesXml],
                                ['benefits', benefitsXml],
                                ['priorities', prioritiesXml],
                                ['difficulties', difficultiesXml],
                                ['factors', factorsXml],
                                ['ratings', ratingsXml]
                            ]);

                            $('#Project', $content).html(html);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Each `Repository.Projects.*` method contains an asynchronous call to get data.  The function passed in is the callback, which is passed the resulting data on success.  The Repository handles the errors with a generic function, so I don't need to pass in an error function.  I need to ensure each of these has been called, and the data returned, prior to the xslt transformation.

The methods in `Repository.Projects.*` all look like this

```
GetStages: function (successCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "DataRepository.asmx/GetStages",
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        dataType: "json",
        success: successCallback,
        error: Repository.FailureCallback
    });
}
```

It seems like I should be able to rewrite this, I just can't see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want all of your functions under `Repository.Projects.*` to return the `$.ajax` call (which itself returns a deferred instance).

```
GetStages: function() {
  return $.ajax(...);
}
```

Then you can use this code:

```
$.when(
  Repository.Projects.GetStages()
  ,Repository.Projects.GetBenefits()
  ,Repository.Projects.GetPriorities()
  ,Repository.Projects.GetDifficulties()
  ,Repository.Projects.GetFactors()
  ,Repository.Projects.GetRatings()
)
  .then(done, fail)
;

// success function
function done(stageResponse, benefitResponse, ...) {
  /*
  each param is the success callback from jquery.ajax.success
  arguments are [ data, textStatus, jqXHR ] 
  */
  var 
    stageXML = $.parseXML(stageResponse[0].d)
    ,benefitXML = $.parseXML(benefitResponse[0].d)
    ...
  ;

  Repository.Projects.GetProjectRatings(...)
}

// error function
function fail() { }
```

EDIT:

You could make this cleaner by wrapping the `Repository.Projects.*` with their own deferred objects.

```
function extractResult($ajax) {
  return $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
    $ajax
      .done(function(response) {
        dfd.resolve(response.d);
      })
      .fail(function(jqXhr) {
        // pass stuff to the failed function
        dfd.reject(...);
      })
    ;
  }).promise();
}
```

Keep in mind the cleaner implementation won't work with the code above. The success function will only receive the contents that it needs to pass to `$.parseXML`. So you could change the done function variables to `$.parseXML(stageResponse)`.

If the only thing `Repository.Projects.Get*` functions do is make `$.ajax` requests, I'd get rid of them entirely.

Sexy way:

```
$.when.apply($
  ,$.map([
    // these could be directly replaced with calls to $.ajax(...)
    Repository.Projects.GetStages()
    ,Repository.Projects.GetBenefits() 
    ,Repository.Projects.GetPriorities()
    ,Repository.Projects.GetDifficulties()
    ,Repository.Projects.GetFactors()
    ,Repository.Projects.GetRatings()
  ], exctractResult)
)
   .done(function(stageResponse, benefitResponse, ...) {
     var 
       stageXML = $.parseXML(stageResponse)
       ,benefitXML = $.parseXML(benefitResponse)
       ...
     ;

     ...
   })
 ;
```